# How to disable an Entry on tkinter when a Checkbutton is unchecked using for loop and dictionary

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter.checkbutton

I'm working on a Windows application for my work and my knowledge on Python is very limited, so I didn't know how to figure this out :

I want to make each entry widget inside the frame disabled when its checkbutton is unchecked and enabled when its checkbutton is checked and make them all checked by default.
I tried this code that I took part of it from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XerT3-rrOmQ) but it didn't work as expected.

```
from tkinter import *

class Principal():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root= Tk()
        self.root.geometry('800x800') 

        self.prixArticlesFrame = LabelFrame(self.root, text="Prix des articles", width=2000)
        self.prixArticlesFrame.place(relx = 0.75, rely = 0.15,anchor = N)

        self.DefautArticlesCheckButton={
            "Deblai" : IntVar(),
            "Remblai" : IntVar(),
            "Blocage" : IntVar(),
            "Beton de propreté": IntVar(),
            "Beton armé": IntVar(),
            "Acier à haute adherence": IntVar(),
            "Joint de dilatation": IntVar(),
            
        }
        for index, (key, value) in enumerate(self.DefautArticlesCheckButton.items()):
            self.cur_check = Checkbutton(self.prixArticlesFrame, 
            text=key,variable=self.DefautArticlesCheckButton[key], onvalue=1, 
            offvalue=0,command=self.ArticlesEntryState) 
            self.cur_check.grid(row=index, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="W")

        self.DefautArticlesEntries={
            "Deblai" : StringVar(),
            "Remblai" : StringVar(),
            "Blocage" : StringVar(),
            "Beton de propreté": StringVar(),
            "Beton armé": StringVar(),
            "Acier à haute adherence": StringVar(),
            "Joint de dilatation": StringVar(),
            
        }

        for index, (key, value) in enumerate(self.DefautArticlesEntries.items()):
            self.cur_entry = 'DefautArticlesEntries' +key
            
            self.cur_entry=Entry(self.prixArticlesFrame,width=10,
                          textvariable=self.DefautArticlesEntries[key])
            self.cur_entry.grid(row=index,column=2,padx=10)
            self.cur_entry.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.root.mainloop()
    
    def ArticlesEntryState(self):
        for index, (key, value) in enumerate(self.DefautArticlesCheckButton.items()):
            
            if self.DefautArticlesCheckButton[key].get() == 1:
                self.cur_entry.grid(row=index,column=2,padx=10)
                self.cur_entry.config(state=NORMAL)

            elif self.DefautArticlesCheckButton[key].get() == 0:
                self.cur_entry.config(state=DISABLED)

app = Principal()
```

[here is what I got in gif image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyzyK.gif)

What I have done wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You have used same instance variable for all checkbuttons and another instance variable for all entries.  You need to use two arrays to store those checkbuttons and entries.

Comment: I thought textvariable=self.DefautArticlesEntries[key] will store for each checkbutton its own off/on value because it's iterable through the dictionary. Otherwise could you show me piece of code that I need to change?

Comment: You used `self.cur_entry` inside `ArticlesEntryState()`, but `self.cur_entry` refers to the last entry created `Principal.__init__()`.  So you need to use list or dict to store the instances of entries instead of those `StringVar`s.

Comment: @acw1668 I really appreciate your help. I managed to figure it out by creating a list and append entries to it. Should I edit my question or answer it to make the update for others whom looking for solution to the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want all buttons checked by default, all variables should have an initial value that matches their `onvalue`.

Besides, both dicts refer to the variables rather than the actual widgets, so each `Entry` must be bound to the scope of the corresponding `IntVar` trace callback - otherwise, only the last loop item is referenced:

```py
        for index, (key, value) in enumerate(self.DefautArticlesCheckButton.items()):
            value.set(1)
            check = Checkbutton(self.prixArticlesFrame, text=key, variable=value)
            check.grid(row=index, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="W")

        # ...

        for index, (key, value) in enumerate(self.DefautArticlesEntries.items()):
            entry = Entry(self.prixArticlesFrame, width=10, textvariable=value)
            entry.grid(row=index, column=1, padx=10)

            var = self.DefautArticlesCheckButton[key]
            handler = lambda *_, e=entry, v=var: e.config(state=NORMAL if v.get() else DISABLED)
            var.trace('w', handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding. you are asking to link check button and Line Edit. i given example code to link.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

def test():
    if e['state'] == 'normal':
        e['state'] = 'disabled'
    else:
        e['state'] = 'normal'

w=Tk()
e=Entry()
e.pack()
cb=Checkbutton(command=test)
cb.select()
cb.pack()
w.mainloop()
```

Comment: As you can see on the code above I created Entries and Checkbuttons using for loop. Then I created a method that verify if the checkbutton is checked or not then disable and enable its Entry accordenly. I think the problem is that textvariable that I assigned for the checkbutton return to only one checkbutton and not eachone on the list

Answer (score 0):

Update:

As @acw1668 said, I used `self.cur_entry` to change the `entry`'s state when `checkbutton` is checked or unchecked and this only change the last `entry`'s state.
I created instead a list and appended the entries created to it :

```
from tkinter import *

class Principal():
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.root= Tk()

        self.root.geometry('800x800') 
        
        self.AjouterArticleFrame = LabelFrame(self.root, text="Ajouter un article", width=2000)
        self.AjouterArticleFrame.place_forget()

        self.DefautArticlesCheckButton={
            "Deblai" : IntVar(value=1),
            "Remblai" : IntVar(value=1),
            "Blocage" : IntVar(value=1),
            "Beton de propreté": IntVar(value=1),
            "Beton armé": IntVar(value=1),
            "Acier à haute adherence": IntVar(value=1),
            "Joint de dilatation": IntVar(value=1),
            }
        
        self.variablesList=[]
        for index, (key, value) in enumerate(self.DefautArticlesCheckButton.items()):
            checkbutton_=Checkbutton(self.prixArticlesFrame, text=key,variable=self.DefautArticlesCheckButton[key], onvalue=1, offvalue=0,command=self.DefaultArticlesEntryState)
            checkbutton_.grid(row=index, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="W")
            self.variablesList.append(self.DefautArticlesCheckButton[key])

        
        self.DefautArticlesPrix=[
            "Deblai" ,
            "Remblai" ,
            "Blocage" ,
            "Beton de propreté" ,
            "Beton armé" ,
            "Acier à haute adherence" ,
            "Joint de dilatation",
        ]
        self.DefautArticlesPrixEntriesWidgets=[]


        for i in self.DefautArticlesPrix:
            entry_prix=Entry(self.prixArticlesFrame,width=10)
            entry_prix.grid(row=self.DefautArticlesPrix.index(i),column=2,padx=10)
            self.DefautArticlesPrixEntriesWidgets.append(entry_prix)


    def DefaultArticlesEntryState(self):
        for i in range(len(self.variablesList)):
            if int(self.variablesList[i].get()) == 1:
                self.DefautArticlesPrixEntriesWidgets[i].grid(row=i,column=2,padx=10)
                self.DefautArticlesPrixEntriesWidgets[i].config(state=NORMAL)

            elif int(self.variablesList[i].get()) == 0:
                self.DefautArticlesPrixEntriesWidgets[i].config(state=DISABLED) 

app = Principal()
```